# Ubuntu with ZFS and Timeshift starts only in Live USB Mode

Tags: live-usb, 20.10, timeshift

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.10 and choose the ZFS, then installed Timeshift and it only starts in Live USB Mode. Why?

USB install stick has been removed.

Comment: Remove the usb then you should see the error that is keeping the system from booting.

Comment: There is no usb...bruh, I'm stupid, but not that stupid.

Comment: Timeshift does not support backing up a ZFS root fs. See https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/529#issuecomment-927019139 and https://github.com/linuxmint/timeshift/issues/56